# The cone over separable C*-algebra is also separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For a C*-algebra $A$, the *cone* over $A$ is $CA=C_{0}(0,1]\otimes A$ ,

**My question**: If $A$ is separable, $CA$ is also separable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The tensor product of separable algebras is separable. You can construct a dense subset of the tensor product by taking the algebraic tensor of two countable dense subsets of each algebra.

Comment: Yeah, $C_{0}(0,1]$ is separable because it can be regard as the convergence of polynominals. Thanks.